# SharePoint workflow regular expression not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I am checking for a string in SharePoint 2013 SPD workflow using regular expression but it is not working. My condition is:

```
If Current Item:UserDepartment matches regular expression /\W(technology)\W/i  
   Log Test1 to the workflow history list  
Else  
   Log Test2 to the workflow history list
```

And it always prints "Test2". The "UserDepartment" field contains value "Information Technology" and I am trying to check if it contains string "technology" case insensitive using above regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regular expression:

```
(?i)(?<= |^)technology(?= |$)
```

My test result:

https://regex101.com/r/dpOWuf/1